# Derive and subclass a directive so ContentChildren can find it?

Tags: angular

I have a component HelloComponent. This component takes all content children which is of type MyButtonDirective and renders a button tag for each of them.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `
  <p>{{buttons.length}}</p>
  <button *ngFor="let b of buttons" (click)="b.onClick()">{{b.text}}</button>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent  {
  @ContentChildren(MyButtonDirective, {descendants: true}) buttons: QueryList<MyButtonDirective>;
}


@Directive({
  selector: 'my-button'
})
export class MyButtonDirective  {
  @Input() text: string;
  @Output() click: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

  onClick() {
    console.log('my-button clicked');
    this.click.emit();
  }
}
```

Is there a way I can subclass or derive from MyButtonDirective to create a new directive och component that will be included in the contentchildren of the HelloComponent?

```
<hello>
  <my-button></my-button>
  <my-button></my-button>
  <extra-button></extra-button>   <-- How can this be included in contenchildren of Hello?
</hello>
```

I've made a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-custom-sub-components?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts) for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to simplify, I've created and `AbstractButton`

```
abstract class AbstractButton {
    text: string;
    abstract onClick();
}
```

The existing `MyButtonDirective` & `ReplayButton` now extends `AbstractButton`

```
@Directive({
    selector: 'my-button',
    providers: [{provide: AbstractButton, useExisting: forwardRef(() => MyButtonDirective)}]
})
export class MyButtonDirective extends AbstractButton {
    ...
}
```

The `HelloComponent` stays the same except the type in `ContentChildren`

```
...
export class HelloComponent  {
    @Input() name: string;
    @ContentChildren(AbstractButton, {descendants: true}) buttons: QueryList<AbstractButton>;
}
```

I also see you have `ExtraButtonComponent` which had the template `<my-button>`, but I am unsure if this would work, as its inside another component and is a child of that

Check out the [StackBlitz Demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-custom-sub-components-gztc1t).

Comment: This, works great. Thanks. I've been searching for this. :) Regarding the ExtraButtonComponent I've read that the ContentChildren don't work between ng-content barriers. Can that be the reason it's not working here?

Comment: After much digging, I've found this link (for bookmark) which is exactly what you were trying to achieve with `extra-button`. Unfortunately such feature doesn't work. If you're using content project to projet `my-button` in `extra-button`, that would work.(Look at Eliseo's answer)  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52653376/angular-using-contentchildren-to-get-children-inside-another-component